# How to upload a file in Jira Issue using python?

Tags: python, jira

I need to upload a file to jira issue using python and attach the file in a particular comment.

```
jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment='inputFile.xlsx')

# read and upload a file (note binary mode for opening, it's important):
with open('inputFile.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
    jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment=f)

# attach file from memory (you can skip IO operations). In this case you MUST provide `filename`.

attachment = StringIO()
attachment.write(data)
jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment=attachment, filename='content.txt')
```

I took this code from the jira documentation but I am not sure how the attachment.write(**data**) statement is working.

How is the data variable used here?

Answer (score 1):

The `attachment.write(data)` part of the example assumes you have a variable called `data` that points to a string.  That part of the example is intended to show how you would upload an attachment when you don't already have a file containing the data that you want to attach to the issue.  It would be given the name `content.txt` in the issue, but you could pick any value for the attachment file name.

[StringIO is a file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) that you would interact with as if you were interacting with a file that you opened like this:

```py
file_name = 'content.txt'
data = 'foo'

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:  # open for writing in text mode
    f.write(data)
```

`StringIO` (and `BytesIO`, the binary equivalent) objects exist only in memory, but many functions that accept file-like objects will accept them as if they were files that you opened via `open(...)`.

Each of those `jira.add_attachment(...)` calls are independent of each other - you only need to use one of those approaches at a time.